# Multi window is disabled after upgrading from 4.1.2 to 4.2.2

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-tab

Multi-window icon is disabled after upgrading samsung galaxy tab from 4.1.2 to 4.2.2.

[image: Current Software status] [image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Anybody fixed this problem ?
Any idea how to fix this without doing a factory reset ?

Comment: Have you tried turning it back on in the Settings?

Comment: It is disabled in the settings as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A factory reset seems to work for some people. You might want to back-up your files / data before doing this.

**Source:** [Problems with Jelly Bean 4.2.2 update](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-8-0/307512-problems-jelly-bean-4-2-2-update.html)

Comment: Yes It works after a factory reset and updating again, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just hold the <kbd>back</kbd> key and it will come back. It's probably in hidden mode since the icon is highlighted and  showed as ON in the screenshot provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can get back all the options by going to Settings > My device > Home screen mode > Standard mode. Now, all your missing options are there.

For multitasking, enable multitasking from notification tray then long press the 'back button' to have sidebar appears on screen. Now, you can enjoy multitasking back.